# Type casting concept in java

Tags: java, swing, casting

I am using Swing for GUI implementation. I have stored all the components in a hashmap.

```
Map<String, Component> myMap = new HashMap<String, Component>();
```

I am storing JLabel, JButtton, JTextFields and some other components.

The following statement works:

```
myMap.get("a_JLabel").setFont(MY_FONT_VARIABLE);
```

In above statement does the map return the object of type JLable automatically ?

But the following with JButton is not working:

```
myMap.get("a_JButton").addActionListener(this);
```

It gives the following error:

```
Cannot find symbol - method
addActionListener(NAME_OF_MY_CLASS)
```

Doesn't it return an object of type JButton here?
And  it works if I type cast the hashmap return value as JButton as below:

```
JButton a_JButton = (JButton) myMap.get("a_JButton");
a_Jbutton.addActionListener(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not related to type casting.

```
myMap.get("a_JLabel").setFont(MY_FONT_VARIABLE);
```

The above scenario works because the `setFont()` method is present in the abstract class `Component`. You can check the [list of methods available in this class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html).

You can see `addActionListener` method is not present in the abstract class. But it is present in the subclass `Button` . So here you need to first type cast it and then use this method